# How can I combine more than two collections in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have more than two collections. Each collection has fields which are similar to the foreign key in MySQL. How can I display the whole collection's data.
 my example colletions.

collection one:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Addmodule',{

    chapterid: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Addchapter' },
    modul: String
});
```

collection two:

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Addchapter',{

    subjectid: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Addsubject' },
    chapter: String
});
```

collection three:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Addsubject',{

    classid: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Addclass' },
    subject: String
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new version of mongodb(3.2), you can merge the collections. Please take a look [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation method. Also you can check the examples in this page. If you have further questions, please feel free to ask, because your question is too general.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Edit 1:

You do not need to use `'$lookup'` method in this case. You can simply use `populate` method. Like:

```
Addmodule
  .find({})
  .populate({
    path: 'chapterid',
    populate: {
      path: 'subjectid',
      populate: { path: 'classid', model: 'Addclass' }
    }
  })
  .exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.json(data);
  });
```

or simply

```
Addmodule
  .find({})
  .populate({
        path: 'chapterid.subjectid.classid',
        model: 'Addclass'           
  })
  .exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.json(data);
  });
```

Because I would not suggest to use lookup if you do not merge 2 array collection (like left join in sql). I can try to add an example if you would like to see lookup version.

Comment: is it possible to more than two collections?

Comment: Please add an example schema into your question. Because it is not clear what kind of collection join you want. It can be same level multiple subDocuments in one schema or double-nested array. So, It would be better if you add an example schema.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support joins.
But from version 3.2 they have added support of left outer join through $lookup operator in aggregation pipeline.

For more detailed description regarding $lookup operator please refer the documentation mentioned in following url

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/