# How can I fetch data from more than one collections in Mongo using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

How I can display details data of a profile when those data stored in more than one collections

tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088352/how-can-i-combine-more-than-two-collections-in-mongo)

```
 const profile = await userKushala
      .find({_id: '5cd407c741f9e7373f10362c'})
      .populate({
        path: 'settingId',
        populate : {
            path : 'specialty',
          populate : {
            path: 'hospital_attached'
          }
        }
      })
```

// First Collection(Basic Info.)

```
const userRegisterSchema = new Schema({
userType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
mobile: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
settingId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'providerSetting'
}
})
```

// Second Collection(Detailed Info.)

```
const serviceProfileUpdate = new Schema({
   specialty :[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'specialtyMasterCsv'
}],
category: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'categoryMasterCsv'
}],
subscriptionPlan: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'planMasterCsv'
},
medicine: {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'kushalaUser' 
}
})
```

//Data in Mongo

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"5cd93ea6bd96e43664f49bf3"
   },
   "specialty":[  
      {  
         "$oid":"5cda85f26ffe60259a75ba17"
      },
      {  
         "$oid":"5cda85f26ffe60259a75ba18"
      }
   ],
   "category":[  
      {  
         "$oid":"5cda85f26ffe60259a75ba17"
      },
      {  
         "$oid":"5cda85f26ffe60259a75ba18"
      }
   ],
   "subscriptionPlan":{  
      "$oid":"5cda85f26ffe60259a75ba17"
   },
   "medicine":{  
      "$oid":"5cd407c741f9e7373f10362c"
   },
   "__v":{  
      "$numberInt":"0"
   }
}
```

Expected Result will be from all the collections data should fetch but with the code I have it's giving the result till specialty but after that it's printing only ObjectID

Comment: Use `model` along with the `path`.

Comment: didn't get you @ShivamPandey can you please explain more

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done and it's working still if anyone has a better solution, most welcome. Hope it helps someone.

```
const profile = await userKushala
      .find({_id: '5cd407c741f9e7373f10362c'})
      .populate({
        path: 'settingId',
        populate : {
            path : 'specialty category subscriptionPlan medicine'
            }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to populate like this:

```
.populate([
    {path:'category',model:'categoryMasterCsv'},
    {path:'subscriptionPlan',model:'planMasterCsv'},
    {path:'medicine',model:'kushalaUser'}])
```

This is the method I use daily.